# Application test to verify caching on an endpoint with ETag

Tags: symfony, etag

I'm trying to test caching, but second response is not 304, but still 200. Controller works great, tried with several HTTP clients and also while debugging the test. But in the test response is different, by some reason

Also tried using `disableReboot` or `reboot` on the client, but no effect

It feels like something is missing to be done in the test

Symfony 6.3
PHPUnit 10.4

```
public function testCache() {
    $client = static::createClient();

    $client->request('GET', '/test?param=123');

    $response = $client->getResponse();

    $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();

    $etag = $response->getEtag();

    $client->request('GET', '/test?param=123', [
        'headers' => [
            'If-None-Match' => $etag
        ]
    ]);

    $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(Response::HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED); // 200 instead of 304
}
```

Example of the response I receive:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Age:              1
Cache-Control:    public
Content-Length:   76
Content-Type:     application/json
Date:             Mon, 19 Feb 2024 22:03:45 GMT
Etag:             "bc4a907bcc4d3e601993f1646938d2a2"
X-Content-Digest: en1c1a61e2a1702c01d3298b4b204a21dd
X-Robots-Tag:     noindex
X-Symfony-Cache:  GET /test?param=123&headers%5BIf-None-Match%5D=%22bc4a907bcc4d3e601993f1646938d2a2%22&param2=321: stale, valid, store
```

Comment: That behavior is provided by the http server or a reverse proxy.  A possible workaround for your test would be to enable the symfony HTTP cache:  https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache.html

Comment: it is enabled for tests and 304 is returned in the controller. But test does not see that and still returns 200. However Age header is added

Comment: found this https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#multiple-requests-in-one-test

but tbh no idea what I should do in my case

Answer (score 1):

Reason of this issue, as always a little bit silly - the incorrect way of passing headers

```
GET /test?param=123&headers%5BIf-None-Match%5D=%22bc4a907bcc4d3e601993f1646938d2a2%22&param2=321: stale, valid, store
```

That's why there is a header in query params here

Correct way to pass the header is like this:

```
$client->request('GET', $endpointUrl, [], [], ['HTTP_If-None-Match' => $etag]);
```

Works like a charm